# Functional equation of divisibility: $m^2+f(n)\mid mf(m)+n$

Tags: functional-equations

I am struggling with the following issue:

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{N}_{+}\to\mathbb{N}_{+} $, such that for all positive integers $m$ and $n$, there is the divisibility
> $$m^2+f(n)\mid mf(m)+n\text.$$
> $\mathbb{N}_{+}$ stands for the set of positive integers.

I've tried various substitutions but I  dont know how to solve functional equations of this form therefore I couldn't manage to find any $f$. I think this is a interesting problem so I'd like to know the answer.

Comment: $f(n)=n$ is a solution.

Comment: Can you prove there are No others?

Comment: Well, as a start, I can show that $f(1)=1$.  Proof:  setting $n=1$ we see that $m^2+f(1)$ divides $mf(m)+1$ for all $m$.  But if there were a prime $p\,|\,f(1)$ then taking $m=p$ gives a contradiction, hence there is no such $p$ which implies that $f(1)=1$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, that's just what I needed to solve the problem! :)

Comment: How do we see that $m^2+f(1)$ divides $mf(m)+1$?

Comment: Look at what you are given and take $n=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @lulu for showing that $f(1)=1$.  Now I can finish the problem by proving that the identity is the only possibility for $f$.

---

Suppose that there exists $m$ such that $f(m)<m$.  Then taking $n=1$ we have
$$m^2+1=m^2+f(1)\le mf(m)+1<m^2+1\ ,$$
a contradiction.  Now suppose there exists $n$ such that $f(n)>n$.  Taking $m=1$, we have
$$1+n<1+f(n)\le f(1)+n=1+n\ ,$$
another contradiction.  Thus $f(n)=n$ for all $n$.

---

**Addendum**.  Proof that $f(1)=1$.  This proof was provided in a comment by Lulu, I'm copying it verbatim here in case the comment disappears in the future.

Setting $n=1$ we see that $m^2+f(1)$ divides $mf(m)+1$ for all $m$.  But if there were a prime $p\mid f(1)$ then taking $m=p$ gives a contradiction, hence there is no such $p$ which implies that $f(1)=1$.